# Uninstalling Nokia Flasher Harmattan

Tags: command-line, macos

My MacBook Pro runs El Capitan. By mistake, I installed Nokia's flasher 3.12.1 (which they say is for Harmattan - to be honest, I do not really know what this means, but I content myself to know this is the wrong one). It is a command line utility. Now I would like to uninstall it, but I do not know how to locate all related files (they are spread in various locations - this is all I know). I tried to run again the installer and look at its log, but I cannot understand it. Any idea?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the exact software you installed?

Comment: @grgarside - software probably downloaded from [here](http://www.fladnag.net/downloads/telephone/n900/tools/). Can't find any other Mac-based Nokia flash apps with my limited Googling skills. :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package available for download at [MacFlasher_3.12.1.dmg](http://www.fladnag.net/downloads/telephone/n900/tools/MacFlasher_3.12.1.dmg) contains the following files which you can remove manually. You can also remove the package receipt from `/var/db/receipts/`.

[image]

To find this list of files from the package, I extracted the package to a custom location using the following, then inspected the contents of the temporary directory.

```
pkgutil --expand /path/to/nokia_flasher.pkg /path/to/temporary
```

For an automated solution, try using [UninstallPKG](https://www.corecode.io/uninstallpkg/). This will parse the package receipt and allow you to remove the files.

Comment: This is exactly what I need. How did you find the various files? Did you install the package and read the receipt?

Comment: @Enrico See edit, you don't need to install the package.

Comment: Well done, I successfully deleted everything. Now I would like to install the flasher 3.5. It is designed for a 32 bit system (I think it would run on Lion). The installer shows up a warning about the program being possibly harmful for my system. What can I do? Maybe it is better that I post another question?

Comment: @Enrico Yeah maybe worth a separate question but also try searching first. I have no experience with this specific software but that message sounds like Gatekeeper. The MacFlasher package mentioned in this question didn't have a Developer ID and threw Gatekeeper for me initially. Try right-clicking on the package, then selecting Open, then Open on the modal that now appears.

Comment: I tried right-clicking etc. but with no result. The error message says "This package is incompatible with this version of OS X and may fail to install" and also notes that it may damage my system. So I don't want to try unless I'm sure of what happens. I don't think this message is due to Gatekeeper. I already removed com.apple.quarantine from the package attributes.

Comment: @Enrico Indeed that's not Gatekeeper. I have a blog post about this which is #1 on Google for this error: [Package is incompatible with this version of OS X](https://georgegarside.com/blog/macos/package-incompatible-installer/)

Comment: That's it! What would you do now? Extract the package manually, maybe with pkgutil, and place the files manually? Or disable Rootless?

Comment: @Enrico This depends entirely on the specific software. I couldn't say either way unfortunately.

Comment: [Here](http://web.archive.org/web/20131117084237/http://skeiron.org/tablets-dev/maemo_dev_env_downloads/) is the software (maemo flasher for Leopard and Snow Leopard, x86, 32 bit). If you may help me, I think it be a good idea that I post a question and you answer it - it may be useful to others.

Comment: @Enrico After much investigation, I have finally worked out how to install that package, I think! Link me to your new question and I'll post the answer there.